# Weird Unity issue - base and class interface type map to same class but gives wrong resolve result when reference the base interface

Tags: unity-container

I defined 2 types, a base interface and child interface inherited from base. Both type map to the same implementation class in the Unity configuration. In a container class whose property defined as base interface. Finally after Unity resolves my container class, I found the value of resolved property is from a child interface instead of the base interface I configured in there. Below is the code and Unity configuration. I know I can use name to differentiate it but try to understand how unity treat this scenario.

Code:

`IBaseInterface` defines a property `string BaseString`.

```
public interface IBaseInterface
{
    string BaseString { set; get; }
}
```

`IChildInterface` inherited from `IBaseInterface` and defines a property `string ChildString`

```
public interface IChildInterface : IBaseInterface
{
    string ChildString { set; get; }
}
```

`ChildClass` implements `IChildInterface` defines 2 properties, `BaseString` and `ChildString`

```
public class ChildClass : IChildInterface
{
    public string BaseString { set; get; }
    public string ChildString { set; get; }
}
```

`ContainerClass` contains a property `impl` whose type is `IBaseInterface`

```
public class ContainerClass
{
    public IBaseInterface impl { set; get; }
}
```

Unity Configuration:

Register type `IBaseInterface` maps to `ChildClass` with 2 properties whose value are started with `IBaseInterface`

```
  <register type="IBaseInterface" mapTo="TestUnity.ChildClass, TestUnity">
    <lifetime type="transient"/>
    <property name="BaseString" value="IBaseInterface_BaseString" />
    <property name="ChildString" value="IBaseInterface_ChildString" />
  </register>
```

Register type `IChildInterface` maps to the same type, `ChildClass` with 2 properties whose value are started with `IChildInterface`

```
  <register  type="IChildInterface" mapTo="TestUnity.ChildClass, TestUnity">
    <lifetime type="transient" />
    <property name="BaseString" value="IChildInterface_BaseString" />
    <property name="ChildString" value="IChildInterface_ChildString" />
  </register>
```

Register type `ContainerClass` with name `Test` and mapto `Container` class. It has one property `impl` whose `dependencType` is `IBaseInterface`.

```
  <register name="Test" type="TestUnity.ContainerClass, TestUnity" mapTo="TestUnity.ContainerClass, TestUnity">
    <lifetime type="transient" />
    <property name="impl" dependencyType="IBaseInterface" />
  </register>
```

After the program run, the instance of `ContainerClass` resolved has property `impl` and the string values of its properties are started with `IChildInterface` which is from the type `IChildInterface`.

Comment: From the unity source code, seems the build plan only cares about mapto and name, no from at all so for the registered type with same mapto but without name, the resolved result is not consistent, depends on the order of the definition.